# How does App Store "complete my bundle" work when I've spent more than the bundle cost?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I have bought the Hitman app for $4.99. When I checked for the app bundle, it says `GET`. Does this mean that the bundle is free, or do I still have to pay for it?

[image: The GO Collection app bundle]

Answer (score 7):

Since you’ve already paid more for one app than the total cost of the bundle, you get the rest of the bundle for free. This is why it says **GET** without a price.

If you had to pay anything, it would show you a price instead. For instance, in my case I see **$3.99** where you see **GET**.

iTunes albums work the same way. Every time you purchase a track on an album, the cost to complete the album goes down, as reflected on the **Purchase** button. If the cumulative cost you’ve paid for the tracks on an album exceeds the cost of the album as a whole, the button changes to **GET** and you can download the remaining tracks “for free.”